# Hibernate validator validate empty field where is not @NotEmpty

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have problem with Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.

The problem is, that the validator is validating fields with are empty and don't have @NotEmpty annotations.

When person's web form gets submitted and address, phone, fax and webpage are not set, an validation error is thrown. I think that's wrong, because there is no @NotEmpty annotation. I want skip fields with don't have @NotEmpty annotation.

Can anyone explain where the problem is? Thank you.

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private String notifiedBodyCode;
    private Address address;
    private String webpage;
    private String phone;
    private String fax;
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    @NotEmpty(message = "{NotEmpty.NotifiedBody.name}")
    @Length(max = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "notified_body_code", length = 25)
    @Length(max = 25)
    public String getNotifiedBodyCode() {
        return notifiedBodyCode;
    }

    public void setNotifiedBodyCode(String notifiedBodyCode) {
        this.notifiedBodyCode = notifiedBodyCode;
    }

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(https?://)?[a-z_0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}.*$")
    @Column(name = "web", length = 50)
    public String getWebpage() {
        return webpage;
    }

    public void setWebpage(String webpage) {
        this.webpage = webpage;
    }

    @Length(min = 9, max = 20)
    @Pattern(regexp ="[0-9\\+\\s]")
    @Column(name = "phone", length = 20)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Length(min = 9, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "fax", length = 20)
    public String getFax() {
        return fax;
    }

    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }

}
```

**Address**

```
public class Address{


    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private Country country;


    @Length(max = 50)
    @Column( name = "city", length= 50)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Length(max = 100)
    @Column( name = "street", length= 100)
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Length(min = 5, max = 6)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\d\\s]$")
    @Column(name = "zip", length = 6)
    public String getZip() {
        return (zip == null ? "" : zip);
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

**Country**

```
public class Country{

    private String countryName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "country_name", length = 45)
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [id=" + id + ", countryName=" + countryName + "]";
    }

}
```

**EDIT - Problem solved.**

Problem was in `"^"` expression. I have to use `"[^|]"` instead.

Comment: To clarify your answer. You actually had constraint annotations on the fields. Without any annotation no validation occurs, but in your case you also used the @Pattern annotation which was failing for the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

It was hard to understand your question, but I ASSUME that you are saying that you get a validation error when phone is empty.

That would be because you have a @Length annotation with a defined min value.

Comment: But I want skip validating fields with do not have @NotEmpty annotation and are not field. If given field contains any character, then will be validated.

Comment: @Length does return "is valid" if your field is NULL, so perhaps your "phone" is being set to an empty string instead of to NULL in the code that is setting it. Strip from "org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.LenghtValidtor.class": public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
  if ( value == null ) {
   return true;
  }
  int length = value.length();
  return length >= min && length <= max;
 }

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I dont know why are thrown errors "must match "^(https?://)?[a-z_0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}.*$"
length must be between 9 and 20
and other" when are inputs empty. Do yo have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: There is a difference between "Empty" and "null". If your fields are "empty", i.e. they are a "" or a "new String()", they will fail the validation because they don't match your "@Length" nor your "@Pattern" validators. If your fields are NULL, however, then they will pass the validation as long as you don't have a "@NotNull" annotation. So as I commented before, the problem is that your fields are being set to empty strings instead of to null objects

Comment: I did, but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to create a custom constraint annotation to return "true" on null and empty. The problem you may be having is when a user clicks on an input box, but doesn't enter anything, the field automatically sets itself to empty, whereas without any interaction with the field would  (should) return null.

A pretty simple tut >>> http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/ and then you have springs reference documentation >>> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html, also, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html