# Hibernate validator validate field with @Length annotation and without @NotEmpty annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have found [copy of my question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155911/hibernate-validator-validate-empty-field-where-is-not-notempty), but there are no answer, except regular expression.

So i have a model with field "phoneNumber", which has a validation annotation @Length:

```
@Length(min = 3, max = 7)
private String phoneNumber;
```

It has not annotation @NotEmpty, so i wont check filling of it. But hibernate gives me an error, that length must be from 3 to 7. But this field may be empty... What's wrong with me? Or with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other answer I assume you are using Spring MVC.

In Spring MVC you can register [`StringTrimmerEditor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.html) in [`WebDataBinder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html).

Place this into your `@Controller` or `@ControllerAdvice` class:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

and all empty/whitespace strings received from submitted form fields will be automatically converted into `null`s when they binding to your 
`@ModelAttribute` object.

This will prevent `@Length` (and other constraints) to complain, if you not place `@NotEmpty` on the same field explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in that question that you found... you probably are sending empty strings ("") in phoneNumber... since it's an empty string it fails validation (lenght lower than 3). If phoneNumber is null it probably will pass since it does not apply for validation (Unless you use @NotNull...).

That same question has an regular expression that works (according to the autor), so if passing null to phoneNumber doesn't help, it's a good try.

Comment: Tell me please how i can pass null in form if i have a button type "submit" which working without any javascript?

Comment: Hi dikkini, I saw your chat with @ipinyol and I am going to recommend the same. Just check if the string is empty, and if it is, set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate the field with **@Length** it implies that your String cannot be empty, because its length would be 0. However it can be null, because you have not specified **@NotNull**

Comment: Your answer means that i can't check length of field until it could be empty - is it not good and i think you are wrong.

Comment: sorry, could you clarify why I am wrong? Your example is a proof that this is the case. Actually, I'm pointing out the same as @Dalton. Passing empty strings does not help in your case, so, pass null values instead. If you receive empty strings at the back end, simply do an if checking it out and set the attribute to null. If you are sending json to the backend, simply do not the field in the json and you'll receive a null in the maping

Comment: Again. How i can pass null value instead of empty string to field, when i'm using form and submitting it using button type submit without any js?

Comment: actually, in a form you can't. You'll be always sending empty string if the field is empty. However, since your semantics says that an empty string should be treated as null, you can control it in the server, and if receiving an empty string, place a null value in the model

Comment: give me an advice. on what concrete step i have to change empty string ("") to null? broken decision check it with "if then else" on server side (in controller) when i retrieve results from object BindingResult - it is bad way anyway